# How to create mutes leaderboard using JSON

Tags: discord, discord.js

i have a JSON file and it has number of `mutes` thats staff members have,
and i want to create a LeaderBoard command names `$top mutes` shows the top of staff member by mutes.

Also i want to create a command names `$top mutes weekly` and `$top mutes monthly` thats shows the weekly and monthly mutes LeaderBoard.

How?

i didn't try anything beacuse i don't know how to make it

JSON file:

```
{
"``HERE IS THE STAFF MEMBER ID``":{"mutes":0,"bans":0,"warns":0,"tickets":0,"appeals":0,"support":2,"WarnedTimes":0}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the JSON structure you use? Without it we can't really figure out what you want. Please also include things you've tried so far and which parts exactly you need help with

Comment: I did it, and i didn't try anything because i don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file does not have enough information stored to do weekly and monthly top mutes. In order to do those your JSON also has to store mutes in the past week and past month. However, you can refer to the following code to get an array in the form `[[id1, muteCount1], [id2, muteCount2], [id3, muteCount3], ...]` which is sorted with the largest muteCount first and the smallest last.

```
// data should contain the parsed JSON data
var sorted = Object.entries(data) // split the Object into an array in the form [[key, value], [key, value], ...]
    .map(v => [v[0], v[1].mutes]) // replace the object with mutes, warns, bans, etc., into a single number representing the mute count
    .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]); // sort in descending order by number of mutes
```